# Wikipedia definition of graph homomorphism: is this correct?

Tags: graph-theory, definition

Consider the definition of a graph homomorphism given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_homomorphism):

A graph homomorphism $f$ from a graph $G=(V,E)$ to a graph $G'=(V',E')$, written $f:G \rightarrow G'$, is a mapping $f:V \rightarrow V' $ from the vertex set of $G$ to the vertex set of $G'$ such that $\{u,v\}\in E$ implies $\{f(u),f(v)\}\in E'$.

At the beginning the article states "...a graph homomorphism is a mapping between two graphs that respects their structure. ..."

So I was wondering:

> Is it a typo or is "implies" really enough?

Shouldn't it be

A graph homomorphism $f$ from a graph $G=(V,E)$ to a graph $G'=(V',E')$, written $f:G \rightarrow G'$, is a mapping $f:V \rightarrow V' $ from the vertex set of $G$ to the vertex set of $G'$ such that $\{u,v\}\in E$ **if and only if** $\{f(u),f(v)\}\in E'$.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You're confusing the concept of *iso*morphism (with the image) with the concept of *homo*morphism. You are interpreting the verb "respect" too strictly.

In general, a [homomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphism) between two algebraic objects with the same kind of structure (e.g. graphs, groups, fields) is a mapping such that its image has the same kind of structure, as a subobject.

On the other hand, an [isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism) between two object means that they have the *very same* structure or, in other words, that they are indistinguishable by that structure alone.

---

In other words, observe that it is generally very useful to express the notion of subobject as an injective morphism. Your definition would imply that every [subgraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory#Subgraphs) is full, which would be quite limiting.